# Python Question - Using selenium to find specific list item and click

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am using python and selenium. I want to scan the HTML in [This image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0xRK.jpg) and click the "correct size"

The variable "s" in the list "tuplist' will reference a unique shoe size each time the for loop is performed.

When "s" equals size 8 I need the code to loop through the HTML li's and when it finds size 8 click on it. (this will update the price data for prices and sales for that specific size)

```
for i, t, s in tuplist:
    stockx = i
    tickercounter = t
    sizecounter = s
    print('Pulling price data for shoe', tickercounter, 'size', sizecounter)
    #selenium navigate to link and open shoe info page
    browser = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver')
    browser.get(stockx)
    time.sleep(2)
    browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/a/div[1]/div/div').click()
    time.sleep(5)
    browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/span/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/button').click()
    time.sleep(4)
    resultSet = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/span/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/ul')
    options = resultSet.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")
    #selects size 10 in standard sizing menu and pulls pricing data last sale, highest bid, lowest ask from webpage

    #need to take variable s and search for it in list item text, then click list item that contains the correct size.


    browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/span/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/ul/li[8]').click()
    lastsale = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/span/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]').text
    lowestask = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/span/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/a/div[1]/div').text
    highestbid = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/span/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/a/div[1]/div').text
```

Comment: Those xpaths are scary. Any chance you can share the actual URL of the page you are scraping?

Comment: https://stockx.com/air-jordan-1-retro-high-bio-hack     (if you see where it says size, by default it selects "all" i can open the size menu, but cannot have it choose the size specifically.

Comment: the goal is to use the variable s which could be any size shoe 4 5 6 7 8 then click on that size within the size drop down element. By selecting a specific size, it changes the values of the "last sale" "highest bid" and "lowest ask" each size has unique pricing data.

Comment: Have you tried finding the 'li'-elements by CSS Path? I believe something like '.product-content .list-unstyled .title' as CSS Path should find all the 'li' you want to search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so you need to use "elements" to make a list of each of the sizes and then loop through the sizes.

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('li.chakra-menu_menuitem.select-option.css-593qcw')

for x in range(len(elements)):
    print('Sizes available: ' + str(len(elements)))
    elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('li.chakra-menu_menuitem.select-option.css-593qcw')
    size = elements[x].find_element_by_css_selector('div.title').text
    print(size)

    if size == "8.5":
        elements[x].find_element_by_css_selector('div.title').click()
```

Comment: Thank you this worked, I did have to change a typographical error in the CSS selector but once I noticed that it worked perfectly. Thank you!